# Sort and analyse grouped data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to get started with some data-analysis.
Basically I have 2 columns 'number' and 'date' with both reappearing a few times. I want to sort my data  numbers and then for each number group sort the 'date' data.

Finally I want to create another column 'dif' which gives me the difference from the first 'date' of a group to each other 'date' in the cluster.

But it's not working as I expect, how can I implement this?

This is what I got so far, sorting works for the 'number' column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.ExcelFile('result.xlsx')
df=df.parse(0)
df=df.sort_values(['number'], ascending=True)   #sorting
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)  #index reset
number=df['number']     #creating number and date
date=df['date']
df['dif']=''
rowcount=len(df.index)  #create rowcounting as maximum index

print('rowcount:', rowcount) #17 rows, start with 0 up to 16
print(df)   #data is sorted and need to be analzsed

def applyFunc(i):
    if number[i] == number [i+1]:
        if date[i+1]>date[i]: 
             return date[i+1]-date[i]
        else:
             return date[i]-date[i+1]

df['dif']=df.apply(applyFunc)
```

This is my dataframe data without 'date' being sorted and with nothing in the the 'dif' column.

```
    rowcount: 17
    number       date dif
0     1624 2017-01-06    
1     1624 2017-01-07    
2     1633 2017-01-05    
3     1633 2017-01-08    
4     1633 2017-01-14    
5     1716 2017-01-02    
6     1716 2017-01-04    
7     1716 2017-01-04    
8     1716 2017-01-09    
9     2165 2017-01-10    
10    2323 2017-01-07    
11    4564 2017-01-13    
12    4564 2017-01-11    
13    4568 2017-01-12    
14    6565 2017-01-05    
15    6565 2017-01-06    
16    6565 2017-01-09
```

p.s. i tried it with groupby and sort_values for both columns but didnt get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort_values` + `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['number', 'date'])   
df.assign(diff=df.groupby('number')['date']\
               .apply(lambda x: x - x.values[0]))

    number       date   diff
0     1624 2017-01-06 0 days
1     1624 2017-01-07 1 days
2     1633 2017-01-05 0 days
3     1633 2017-01-08 3 days
4     1633 2017-01-14 9 days
5     1716 2017-01-02 0 days
6     1716 2017-01-04 2 days
7     1716 2017-01-04 2 days
8     1716 2017-01-09 7 days
9     2165 2017-01-10 0 days
10    2323 2017-01-07 0 days
12    4564 2017-01-11 0 days
11    4564 2017-01-13 2 days
13    4568 2017-01-12 0 days
14    6565 2017-01-05 0 days
15    6565 2017-01-06 1 days
16    6565 2017-01-09 4 days
```

---

If you want the `diff` column as a column of integers (it's currently a `timedelta` column), then access the `.dt.days` attribute.

```
df['diff'] = df['diff'].dt.days
df

    number       date  diff
0     1624 2017-01-06     0
1     1624 2017-01-07     1
2     1633 2017-01-05     0
3     1633 2017-01-08     3
4     1633 2017-01-14     9
5     1716 2017-01-02     0
6     1716 2017-01-04     2
7     1716 2017-01-04     2
8     1716 2017-01-09     7
9     2165 2017-01-10     0
10    2323 2017-01-07     0
12    4564 2017-01-11     0
11    4564 2017-01-13     2
13    4568 2017-01-12     0
14    6565 2017-01-05     0
15    6565 2017-01-06     1
16    6565 2017-01-09     4
```

Comment: wonderful thanks  a lot! sorting works so far but somehow i dont get the same result as you ( i copied your code, the diff column stays empty?) additionally if i add your second code i get 2 errors:                           TypeError: cannot convert an object of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to a datetimelike index                                          and           AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values                                      anyway big thanks mate:)

Comment: @MaximilianLöffel you need to assign the result of the last line back. `df = df.assign(diff=df.groupby('number')['date']\
               .apply(lambda x: x - x.values[0]))` Did you try that? If it works, don't forget to vote on, and accept the answer. Thanks.